# Forcing a datetime in a form to be on the hour (CLOSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

<< I've manually created the HTML forms I required and they work successfully, so you can ignore this >>

I've created a form that is asking a user to submit a datetime variable. Since it's for scheduling lessons it has to be on the hour (1:00pm, 3:00am, 12:00pm etc). To foolproof the system I've hidden all the fields except the hour and added a dummy minutes drop down that only allows them to pick the "0 minutes" option.

However I've tried several methods to force the minute to be on-the-hour (beginning_of_day, beginning_of_hour, at_midday etc and the .change as shown below) but no matter what the default date remains the present time.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle(eID) {
 var ele = document.getElementById(eID);
 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = "hide";
 }
} 
</script>

<%= month_calendar events: @lessons, previous_link: events_ajax_previous_link, next_link: events_ajax_next_link do |date, events| %>
  <% @formatteddate = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
  onclick="toggle('<%= @formatteddate.to_s%>');return false;">
    <%= date.strftime("#{date.day.ordinalize}") %>
</button></br>

<span id='<%= @formatteddate.to_s%>' class="lesson-submit">
  Add New Lesson Slot (Perth time is used)
  <%= form_for(Lesson.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :starts_at %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :value => date.at_midday, :discard_year => true, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true %>
    <select><option value="00">00</option></select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</span>
<% end %>
```

Can you suggest why the default time isn't being manipulated as I like and is this (in general) a suitable way to force the user to pick an hour only?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use the `select_hour` helper instead?
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour
Then in the controller, use the results to create a DateTime to save to the database.

Comment: Not sure how I'd use that in my form, but `beginning_of_hour` works in the controller before I save it... I'm interested why it wasn't working in my form though. Thanks for the idea!